# How to read from csv depending on user input

Tags: php, csv

I have a csv file containing European football team results. I wish for users to enter a team and then the system to display the results for that team including losses.

I managed to read the csv file with php.

How do read team names from users of the program?

How do I query the CSV file so as to retrieve results for that team?

Read data from http://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1718/I1.csv (Italy Football Results, Season 2017/2018, results; match stats; match, total goals)

This is my code so far in 2 files:

```
<?php

include('init.inc.php');
header('Content-type: text/plain');
print_r(read_csv('I1.csv'));
$data = read_csv('I1.csv');

<?php

function read_csv($filename){
    $rows = array();

    foreach (file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES)as $line){
      $rows[] = str_getcsv($line);
    }

    return $rows;
}

function write_csv($filename, $rows){
    $file = fopen($filename, 'w');

    foreach ($rows as $row){
        fputcsv($file, $row);
    }
    fclose($file);

}
```

Comment: Loop through the array, test if the team column matches the one the user entered and if the score is a loss. If it is, display it in the results.

Comment: @Barmar I am new in php, how do i read the user input? how do I find the score, the csv doesn't talk about lost or won matches

Comment: Well, you have the score, so you know if both goals are different or not. If the score is not even, you know that someone won and the other lost. So, "for every game of the season: if the selected team played and the score is not even, then <do something for a loss case>." The comparison will look something like `if(($selectedTeam == $homeTeam || $selectedTeam == $awayTeam) && $homeGoals != $awayGoals){ /*do something*/ }`. And if you only want a loss for that team, then just make sure to compare only the away score if the selected team played away or the home score if the team played at home.

Comment: @Werokk If it's a web page, you have the user fill in a form. There are many tutorials on how to process forms using PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Football coding:**

The problem is not so hard but first you need to understand the codes in the CSV.

These can be found here:
http://www.football-data.co.uk/notes.txt and is based on home and away games. For example, if you pick a team like Juventus in the first row, you can see they played at Home and the final result "FTR" is "H" meaning they won that match.

You need to get your head around the CSV coding before you can write any PHP!

**EDIT:** Changed implementation on request of requester to operate as a single HTML file.

Assuming you have a web server set up, that is PHP enabled, you can coy-paset the code below into a file and run in in browser. In my case I called the file `test.php` and run it by typing the URL  `localhost:8080/test.php` in the browser. You need to have the 2 files `test.php`and `Results.csv` located at your website home directory. I have IISExpress browser running which listens at port 8080.

**EDIT:** Added losses breakdown at request of asker.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html>
<body> 
<head> 
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
</style>
<head>

<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$teamIn  = "";
$homeLosses = 0;
$awayLosses = 0;
$totalLosses = 0;
$winningTeams = []; // list of winning teams

if ( !($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") )
{  // we reach here only if form was not submitted yet
        $teamIn  = "None";
        $homeLosses = 0;
        $awayLosses = 0;
        $totalLosses = 0;
        $winningTeams = []; 
} 
else
{   // we arrive here only if form is submitted

    $teamIn = ucfirst($_POST["teamName"]);  // make first char of teamname a capital

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // First read the CSV file and make an associative array based on first row titles
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $fileName = "Results.csv";    // CSV File name changed to "Results.csv" 
    $teams = $fields = array(); $i = 0;
    $handle = fopen($fileName, "r");
    if ($handle) {
        while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 4096)) !== false) {
            if (empty($fields)) {
                $fields = $row;
                continue;
            }
            foreach ($row as $k=>$value) {
                $teams[$i][$fields[$k]] = $value;
            }
            $i++;
        }
        if (!feof($handle)) {
            die("Error: unexpected fgets() fail\n");
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
    else{
        die("Did not open file: ".$fileName.PHP_EOL);
    }    


    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //  now make a list of losses and make a list of teams that have beaten the team entered.
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $n = 0;
    foreach ($teams as $team){
        if ( $team['HomeTeam'] == $teamIn ){
            if ($team['FTR'] == "A" ) {
                 $homeLosses++;
                 $winningTeams[$n]['date'] = $team['Date'];
                 $winningTeams[$n]['name'] = $team['AwayTeam'];
                 $winningTeams[$n]['location'] = "at Home";
                 $winningTeams[$n]['goalsFor'] = $team['FTAG'];
                 $winningTeams[$n]['goalsAgainst'] = $team['FTHG'];
                 $n++;
            }
        }
        else if  ($team['AwayTeam']== $teamIn){
            if ($team['FTR'] == "H" ) {
                $awayLosses++;
                $winningTeams[$n]['date'] = $team['Date'];
                $winningTeams[$n]['name'] = $team['HomeTeam'];
                $winningTeams[$n]['location'] = "away";
                $winningTeams[$n]['goalsFor'] = $team['FTHG'];
                $winningTeams[$n]['goalsAgainst'] = $team['FTAG'];
                $n++;
            }    
        }
      }
      $totalLosses = $homeLosses+$awayLosses;

}
// end of PHP section
?>

<!–- This part is the form to enter your team --->
<!–- We submit the form to self- meaning this file --->
<h2>Get Match Results</h2>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">  
   Enter Team Name: <input type="text" name="teamName">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">  
</form>

<!–- This part prints out losses summary --->
<?php
echo "<h2>".$teamIn."</h2>";
echo "<p><b>Summary of Losses</b></p>";
echo "<table>";
echo "  <tr>";
echo "    <th>Team</th>";
echo "    <th>Away Losses</th> ";
echo "    <th>Home Losses</th>";
echo "    <th>Total Losses</th>";  
echo "  </tr>";
echo "  <tr>";
echo "    <td>".$teamIn."</td>";
echo "    <td>".$awayLosses."</td> ";
echo "    <td>".$homeLosses."</td> ";
echo "  </tr>";
echo "</table>";
?>
<!–- This part prints out list of teams who beat the entered team --->
<?php
echo "<p><b>Details of losses</b></p>";
echo "<table>";
echo "  <tr>";
echo "    <th>Beaten By</th>";
echo "    <th>Date</th> ";
echo "    <th>Location</th>";
echo "    <th>Goals For</th>";
echo "    <th>Goals Against</th>"; 
echo "  </tr>";
    foreach ($winningTeams as $winningTeam){
        echo "  <tr>";
        echo "    <td>".$winningTeam['name']."</td>";
        echo "    <td>".$winningTeam['date']."</td>";
        echo "    <td>".$winningTeam['location']."</td>";  
        echo "    <td>".$winningTeam['goalsFor']."</td>"; 
        echo "    <td>".$winningTeam['goalsAgainst']."</td>";     
        echo "  </tr>";
    }
echo "</table>";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This might get you started, but by all means ask again as needed.

Comment: thanks it starts making sense, can you please explain me how to read the user input, I tried making a form action with an input in the html file, but i dont know how to pass it to the php file

Comment: It gives me this error : Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function readline()

Comment: i've added a simple form to your code such as 
     <form method="post" action="">
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
     </form>

Comment: You can run the PHP without a form from the command line. Like "PHP csvRead.php" if your file is called csvRead.php for example. Then readline() will work. Otherwise you need a simpleHTML form and submit. If still not working, let me know and I will assist tomorrow AM, Australia time.

Comment: I tried doing it with a simple form in HTML but it won't take the user input, it says the the readline() function is unrecognised. can you see what im doing wrong?

Comment: Ok I changed code so it all works in a single web page, See how you go.... If it works you might consider to accept the answer by clicking the tick at the top left of the reply section.

Comment: Thanks it works. I am finding it hard to read the file. how can I show a list of team that have won against the selected team? so if I input inter, I should display all the team that have beaten Inter

Comment: Ok very good that it works. I will look at new request tomorrow, but best if you ask a new question, and send me a comment. This question is answered and needs to be closed. You should show some code where you tried, its not so hard!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179492/discussion-between-werokk-and-bcperth).

Comment: Ok sure, Let me know your timezone to pick a time when we are both available. I am in Perth Australia.

Comment: Ah Ok. I see your chat comment. Sorry was not available till now. I will update code in an hour so, maybe you can still meet deadline.